# Angular Universal crashes when reloading the page (routes not working)

Tags: angular, firebase, express, angular-universal

Just deployed Angular Unversal web app at firebase. All routes inside the application works fine, but when trying to access them from the outside, the server returns an error.
Here is the error message:

```
functions: Beginning execution of "ssr"
⚠  functions: TypeError: handler is not a function
    at cloudFunction (/home/dell/Documents/personal/motor-bike/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:608:20
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:582:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:7:71
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (/home/dell/Documents/personal/motor-bike/functions/dist/server.js:6245:33)
    at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:3:12)
    at Run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:575:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:607:15
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2019:17:07:54 +0000] "GET /elektriniai-dviraciai-centrinis-motoras HTTP/1.1" 500 948 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2019:17:07:54 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "http://localhost:5000/elektriniai-dviraciai-centrinis-motoras" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
```

And here is the server.ts file:

```
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
global['TextTrackCueList'] = null;
global['KeyboardEvent'] = null;

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

var app = express()

const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  res.render('index', { req });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short. Just need to add `export` before `var app = express();`